# Tategaki-Writing style in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-text

How to achieve Tategaki-Writing in iOS? I want to display text containing Japanese and English characters vertically.  The expected result is something like [this](http://i62.tinypic.com/ev27g6.jpg).

Here, English characters and numbers are rotated to the right. Is this possible in iOS using `UITextView/CATextlayer/UILabel`?

Anyone can share their idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Core Text or a view using Core Text.

Checkout these links may it helps you out:

1) http://cocoadays-info.blogspot.jp/2012/01/coretexttextview-lccoretext.html

2) https://github.com/novi/LTCoreText

3) https://github.com/hokuron/CTRVerticalTextView

4) http://b.hatena.ne.jp/Watson/iOS/CoreText/

There are some links in Japanese language, you can translate them in english by google translator :).